# Convert jsonb column to a user-defined type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm trying to convert each row in a jsonb column to a type that I've defined, and I can't quite seem to get there.

I have an app that scrapes articles from [The Guardian Open Platform](https://open-platform.theguardian.com/) and dumps the responses (as jsonb) in an ingestion table, into a column called 'body'. Other columns are a sequential ID, and a timestamp extracted from the response payload that helps my app only scrape new data.

I'd like to move the response dump data into a properly-defined table, and as I know the schema of the response, I've defined a type (`my_type`).

I've been referring to the [9.16. JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) in the Postgres docs. I can get a single record as my type:

`select * from jsonb_populate_record(null::my_type, (select body from data_ingestion limit 1));`

produces

| id | type | sectionId | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example_id | example_type | example_section_id | ... |

(abbreviated for concision)

If I remove the limit, I get an error, which makes sense: the subquery would be providing multiple rows to `jsonb_populate_record` which only expects one.

I can get it to do multiple rows, but the result isn't broken into columns:

`select jsonb_populate_record(null::my_type, body) from reviews_ingestion limit 3;`

produces:

| jsonb_populate_record |
| --- |
| (example_id_1,example_type_1,example_section_id_1,...) |
| (example_id_2,example_type_2,example_section_id_2,...) |
| (example_id_3,example_type_3,example_section_id_3,...) |

This is a bit odd, I would have expected to see column names; this after all is the point of providing the type.

I'm aware I can do this by using Postgres JSON querying functionality, e.g.

```
select 
  body -> 'id' as id,
  body -> 'type' as type,
  body -> 'sectionId' as section_id,
  ...
from reviews_ingestion;
```

This works but it seems quite inelegant. Plus I lose datatypes.

I've also considered aggregating all rows in the `body` column into a JSON array, so as to be able to supply this to `jsonb_populate_recordset` but this seems a bit of a silly approach, and unlikely to be performant.

Is there a way to achieve what I want, using Postgres functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need this - to break `my_type` record into columns:

```sql
select (jsonb_populate_record(null::my_type, body)).* 
from reviews_ingestion
limit 3;
-- or whatever other query clauses here
```

i.e. select all from these `my_type` records. All column names and types are in place.
Here is an illustration. My custom type is `delmet` and CTO `t` remotely mimics `data_ingestion`.

```sql
create type delmet as (x integer, y text, z boolean);

with t(i, j, k) as 
(
 values 
 (1, '{"x":10, "y":"Nope", "z":true}'::jsonb, 'cats'), 
 (2, '{"x":11, "y":"Yep", "z":false}', 'dogs'), 
 (3, '{"x":12, "y":null, "z":true}', 'parrots')
)
select i, (jsonb_populate_record(null::delmet, j)).*, k
from t;
```

Result:

| i | x | y | z | k |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | Nope | true | cats |
| 2 | 11 | Yep | false | dogs |
| 3 | 12 |  | true | parrots |